# using ng-webworker with application does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, web-worker

I am building an application with [`ng-webworker`](http://mattslocum.github.io/ng-webworker/) , i built a sample application with ng-webworker and added all the necessary javascript.But it does not work.

I need the function to be executed on the button click.

**Code:**

```
 <md-button ng-click="callworker()">
                    CALL WEBWORKER
 </md-button>
```

**JS:**

```
var routerApp =angular.module('DiginRt', ['ngMaterial','ngWebworker'])
 routerApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope,Webworker) {
function doubler(num) {
    return num * 2;
}
var myWorker = Webworker.create(doubler);
$scope.callworker = function() {
  myWorker.run($scope.value).then(function(result) {
    alert("Answer: " + result);
});
}
```

Here is the [`application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/FcQoTP4PQ6otDJs0aiaJ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your new code link, `$scope.value` is not defined, you have to define it in your `$scope`;

```
var routerApp = angular.module('DiginRt', ['ngMaterial', 'ngWebworker'])
routerApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'Webworker', function ($scope, Webworker) {
    $scope.value = 10; //Added this.
    function doubler(num) {
        return num * 2;
    }

    var myWorker = Webworker.create(doubler);
    $scope.callworker = function () {
        myWorker.run($scope.value).then(function (result) {
            alert("Answer: " + result);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: sorry guys i think i have not given the correct link to the application, can you check now

Comment: Check my edit, you are not defining $scope.value anywhere.

Comment: It's working, do you know how i can do for parrallel processing?

Comment: What do you mean with parallel processing?

Comment: say i need to call a web service to get data of 1 million, how would you do it? if i do in normal way, browser gets stuck

Comment: kinda long answer, but the worker approach is good, and you would need to do async calls to the service. also, you could do it by batch, fire 1 request to get 100k items, when finish, call another 100k items an so on...

Comment: can i call a service(restangular) inside an webworker like doubler